# Subclass THREE.Mesh using prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to subclass `THREE.Mesh` like below ([THREE.Mesh](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/Mesh.js) inherits from [THREE.Object3D](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js)).

```
Planet = function(geometry, material) {
    THREE.Mesh.call(this);

    this.geometry = geometry;
    this.material = material;
};

Planet.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
```

It seems to work fine when I pass in a `SphereGeometry`, except that the `boundRadius` property **is not set** like it would be if I were using just a `THREE.Mesh`.  The scene draws correctly though.

However, when I pass in a `CubeGeometry`, the render loop becomes very not happy.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'radius' of null three.min.js:105
THREE.Frustum.intersectsObject three.min.js:105
render three.min.js:414
starsgl.Application.render Application.js:60
starsgl.Application.animate Application.js:55
starsgl.Application Application.js:50
(anonymous function)
```

I imitated the way that `Three.js` was subclassing `THREE.Object3D` with `THREE.Mesh`.  I must be missing something though.

Comment: Tip. Don't debug with the minified version. Use three.js instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

radius isn't called because geometry isn't set.

```
Planet = function(geometry, material) {
  THREE.Mesh.call(this,geometry,material);
};

Planet.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
```

Comment: Yup, that would definitely be me missing something.  Thank you very much.